# How to add title in marker in google map v2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Hi all here i'm pointing an array of latlng in google map. I've done marking those latlng but not able to point marker title?
so, i put GEvent, i.e addlistener that display only one title.

```
for (var i = 0; i < g_listOfBusinessDetails.length ;i++) 
    {
        point = new GLatLng(g_listOfBusinessDetails[i].mapLocation.latitude, g_listOfBusinessDetails[i].mapLocation.longitude);
        map.setCenter(point, 2);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(g_listOfBusinessDetails[i].name);
        });

    }
```

Comment: if you mean that you see only one info window, it is not possible to open more then one. If you need more then one then you would have to add then as HTML overlays.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common JavaScript problem--you can see a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670356/looping-through-markers-with-google-maps-api-v3-problem) and there's also a nice [blog post](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62) explaining it. The problem is that the variables `marker` and `i`, as well as `g_listOfBusinessDetails`, which you use inside the function are not bound to the values they had when you called `GEvent.addListener`. On the click event, the function gets run with whatever values they have at that point in time (so that for example `i` is presumably `g_listOfBusinessDetails.length`).

You can bound them as required by calling a factory function that creates the handler function for your marker and title like so:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", (function(myMarker, title) {
    return function() {
        myMarker.openInfoWindowHtml(title);
    }
})(marker, g_listOfBusinessDetails[i].name));
```